# Page Title Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, page-title, taxonomy-terms

I have created a custom post type and taxonomy on my website but when I view the taxonomy page it is showing the incorrect page title. Rather than showing 'Taxonomy Term Name' as the Title it is showing the title of the first post shown on that page?

This is my taxonomy page template...

```
<div class="one-whole">

  <!-- Course Tax -->
  <?php


  // Get the taxonomy
  $taxonomy = get_queried_object();

  $id = $taxonomy->term_id;
  $name = $taxonomy->name;
  $slug = $taxonomy->slug;

  ?>

  <h1><?php echo $name; ?> Training Courses</h1>

  <?php echo term_description( $id, $name ) ?>

  <hr>

  <section class="flexbox one-whole">

  <?php // Create a custom loop for all items in this taxonomy


  $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'htl_training',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order'           => 'asc',
            'orderby'        => 'name',
            'tax_query'       => array ( array(
                            'taxonomy'      =>   'course-categories',
                            'terms'         => $taxonomy->slug, // Taxonomy Term to Search in
                            'field'         => 'slug',
                            'operator'      => 'IN')
              )
          );

   $posts = new WP_Query($args);

     if($posts->have_posts()) : 

        while($posts->have_posts()) : 

           $posts->the_post(); ?>

          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="card card-title-below">

              <?php $image = get_field('accrediting_body'); ?>

              <?php if( !empty($image) ){ ?>

                      <?php 

                      // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                      if( have_rows('endorsing_bodies','options') ){

                        // loop through the rows of data
                          while ( have_rows('endorsing_bodies','options') ) { 

                            the_row();

                            $hook = get_sub_field('logo_hook', 'options');
                            $icon = get_sub_field('logo','options');

                            $accrediting_body = get_field('accrediting_body');

                              if( $accrediting_body ){ ?>

                                <div class="training-provider">

                                <?php  if( $accrediting_body === $hook ) {

                                      echo '<img src="' . $icon['url'] . '" alt="' . $hook .'" />';

                                    } ?>

                                </div>

                                  <?php

                              }

                            }

                      } else { } ?>

            <?php } ?>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="non-animated-link">

             <?php htl_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

            </a>

            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>


          </div><!--/ Card -->
          <?php


        endwhile;

     else: 

        echo' Oops, there are no posts';

     endif;

  ?>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </section>

     <!-- Course Tax -->

</div>
```

How can I show the taxonomy term name as the page title?

Answer (score 0):

Use following function to display archive title

```
the_archive_title();
```

More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_title/)